# Duplicate a list in a Pandas Dataframe into a new row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas (associateid) that has a list of codes against an index.  It goes something like this:

```
IndexBudgetCode   AssociateID
Nexusapp_341800   ppc_fli_1111
Nexusweb_120000   ooc_htl_1010
Primweb_1900000   ppc_fli_9999,ppc_fli_1777
```

You can see in some cases, there is more than one associateID in the row - always seperated by a comma, with no spaces.

From this line of code, I can get them into a list:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(budgetdf.AssociateID.str.split(',').tolist(), index=budgetdf.BudgetCode).stack()
```

Which looks like this:

```
AssociateID                    IndexBudgetCode   
[ppc_fli_9999, ppc_fli_1777]   Primweb_1900000
```

But I can't seem to duplicate the list to create this final dataframe:

```
IndexBudgetCode   AssociateID
Nexusapp_341800   ppc_fli_1111
Nexusweb_120000   ooc_htl_1010
Primweb_1900000   ppc_fli_9999
Primweb_1900000   ppc_fli_1777
```

Can someone shed some light on what approach I can use to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to expand the AssociateIDs into separate rows is to
use a generator expression to build the rows:

```
((index, item) 
 for index, row in df['AssociateID'].str.split(',').iteritems() 
 for item in row)
```

You can then pass the generator expression to `pd.DataFrame` to obtain the desired DataFrame.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IndexBudgetCode':['Nexusapp_341800', 'Nexusweb_120000', 'Primweb_1900000'],
    'AssociateID':['ppc_fli_1111', 'ooc_htl_1010', 'ppc_fli_9999,ppc_fli_1777']})
df = df.set_index(['IndexBudgetCode'])

result = pd.DataFrame(((index, item) 
                       for index, row in df['AssociateID'].str.split(',').iteritems() 
                       for item in row),
                      columns=['IndexBudgetCode', 'AssociateID'])
print(result)
```

which yields the DataFrame

```
   IndexBudgetCode   AssociateID
0  Nexusapp_341800  ppc_fli_1111
1  Nexusweb_120000  ooc_htl_1010
2  Primweb_1900000  ppc_fli_9999
3  Primweb_1900000  ppc_fli_1777
```

---

Another way, which does not use the generator expression is

```
result = df.groupby(level=0)['AssociateID'].apply(
    lambda grp: pd.Series(1, index=grp.str.split(',').tolist()))
result.index.names = ['IndexBudgetCode', 'AssociateID']
result = result.reset_index(['AssociateID'])
result = result[['AssociateID']]
```

which yields the Series

```
                  AssociateID
IndexBudgetCode              
Nexusapp_341800  ppc_fli_1111
Nexusweb_120000  ooc_htl_1010
Primweb_1900000  ppc_fli_9999
Primweb_1900000  ppc_fli_1777
```

Comment: can you help me understand why I'm getting a TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.  The dtypes for dataframe all come back as objects..

Comment: Please post the full traceback error message. Since these are hard to read in the comments, please edit your original question and post it there.

Comment: Whoops, apologies.  I was being a bit of an idiot on that one.  I had NaN's that threw the error.  I replaced the NaNs with " " and it iterated perfectly.